# Why are there entries with no runtime stats interval values for DOP_FeedBack feature verification query

Tags: sql-server, query-store, sql-server-2022, dop-feedback

In the SQL2022 Workshop files there is a query used in the demo for DOP_Feedback, which is the below. However, it doesn't have the runtime stats interval so I can't see when the affected queries ran. I eventually want to get the query text for affected queries, but at the moment, I'm trying to understand how I can have entries with NO runtime stats interval data. Here's the original query from the workshop

```
SELECT qsp.query_plan_hash, avg_duration/1000 as avg_duration_ms, 
avg_cpu_time/1000 as avg_cpu_ms, last_dop, min_dop, max_dop, qsrs.count_executions
FROM sys.query_store_runtime_stats qsrs
JOIN sys.query_store_plan qsp ON qsrs.plan_id = qsp.plan_id 
--and qsp.query_plan_hash = CONVERT(varbinary(8), cast(4128150668158729174 as bigint))
ORDER by qsrs.last_execution_time;
GO
```

Here is my query where I have a left join and I have entries with no runtime stats interval. I've also tried to eliminate serial queries from the results by adding this: `WHERE qsrs.last_dop > 1`.

```
SELECT qsp.query_plan_hash, avg_duration/1000 as avg_duration_ms, 
avg_cpu_time/1000 as avg_cpu_ms, qsrs.last_dop,qsrs.min_dop, qsrs.max_dop, qsrs.count_executions, qsrsi.end_time, qsrsi.start_time
FROM sys.query_store_runtime_stats qsrs
JOIN sys.query_store_plan qsp ON qsrs.plan_id = qsp.plan_id
LEFT JOIN sys.query_store_runtime_stats_interval AS qsrsi ON qsrs.runtime_stats_interval_id = qsrsi.runtime_stats_interval_id

--last dop > 1 eliminates serial queries. The max_dop value here should match the max_dop of the server or database
WHERE qsrs.last_dop > 1 AND qsrs.max_dop <=8
ORDER by qsrs.last_execution_time;
```

Comment: Have you considered [opening an issue](https://github.com/microsoft/sqlworkshops-sql2022workshop/issues) so that the authors might have a chance to respond to you about this?

Comment: Sorry, Erik. I had not. I could do that, but I don't know if it's really an issue with the sql2022 code as much as it is trying to understand the Query Store views and the data I'm getting back. But, I understand the point you're making, and I may create an issue. Thank you.

Comment: There’s no need to apologize at all. Just trying to get you fast help.